# How do I apply a perspective transform to a View?

Tags: java, android, matrix, imageview

[image]

I am trying to put my images at an angle just like in the above image :

```
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.widget.ImageView;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivotX, pivotY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

This does not give the same outcome *(please note the images on either side of **Jimmy Hendricks**)*.

How can I get the same look in Android?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: see `View#setRotationY()` method

Comment: I am so sorry for the late reply @pskink. Thank you very much for the suggestion. It worked perfectly. If you like you could put it in an answer and I will accept it. Again, thank you very much. Regards.

Comment: sure, your welcome